# Microsoft teams user detection

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams

I am showing a wordpress website in iframe inside Microsoft teams Tabs. is there any way to detect the loggedIn user in my website?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to wrap your website inside a Teams app (which you can do for example very easily using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview), then you could surface your website as a "Tab" app. Doing this means you can reference the Teams JS library in your code, which will enable you to get a [context object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context). You can get a lot of user information from that.

Be aware though that this context is not really 'trusted' data (it's just inserted via Javascript), so it could be spoofed into your page by a malicious actor. If that's a problem, you should look to implement Tab SSO in your app, which will give you a proper JWT token that you can validate.

Comment: thanks alot. can you explain this as i am fairly new to this. 
```Be aware though that this context is not really 'trusted' data (it's just inserted via Javascript), so it could be spoofed into your page by a malicious actor. If that's a problem, you should look to implement Tab SSO in your app, which will give you a proper JWT token that you can validate.```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a strange warning - took me a little while to understand a similar one from Microsoft when I first saw it. Basically, if you are, for example, taking the user's UPN or AadObjectId from the Teams context, in your Javascript, and sending that to your backend API as a simple POST payload, you can't actually rely on that -really- being the user's identity. An attacker, debugging your web app and seeing the call to your API, could simply send any value they wanted in, for example. If you're building an internal app for your own company's use, that's probably not a major problem.

Comment: If you're building something for public consumption, let's say an app for the Teams store that multilple companies/tenants will use, you want to be more sure that the user is who they say they are. To do this, you need to implement SSO in your tab, which will give you an actual JWT token you can send to your backend API, which you can then validate to confirm is a valid token, and will contain UPN, AadObjectId, TenantID, etc.

Comment: To see more about this go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso and here are some samples: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso and https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso (I worked on the original version of this last one, fyi)

Comment: Thank you @hilton.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. If this has been of use, please go ahead and upvote and/or mark as answer though, so others can find it who might have a similar issue